# set ajax response in php variable

Tags: php, ajax

I am trying to set json response in php variable.After success response my html data is printed in div.
Any Idea How to upload This in a Php variable. it's any idea where I can store this in a session or cookies.

```
$('#pincode').on('change', function() {
    //const formData = $('#formid').serializeArray();
    var address = $("input[name=address]").val();
    var pincode= $("input[name=pincode]").val();
    var price = $("input[name=price]").val();
    var city = $("input[name=city]").val();
    var country =$('#country').val();
    var state = $('#state').val();
    //var state =$(this).val();
    //console.log(formData);

    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
    });

    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        data:{address:address, pincode:pincode, price:price,country:country,state:state,city:city},
        url:'./ava',
        dataType: "text",
        success:function(data){
            $('#gettax').html(data);
            //alert(res);
        },
        error: function (err) {
            console.log(err);
            alert("Something Went Wrong, Please check again");
        }
    });
});
```

Here is mY controller and I m returning a plan text value.and try to restore this in a php variable

```
public function avatax(Request $request){
    $input = $request->all();
    $address=$input['address'];
    $pincode=$input['pincode'];
    $country=$input['country'];
    $state=$input['state'];
    $city=$input['city'];
    $price=$input['price'];
    // print_r(json_decode(json_encode($input)));
    // die();
    //return response()->json(['success'=>$input]);

    $client = new Avalara\AvaTaxClient('phpTestApp', '1.0', 'localhost', 'sandbox');
    $client->withSecurity('ABC', 'ABC');
    // If I am debugging, I can call 'Ping' to see if I am connected to the server
    $p = $client->ping();
    echo('<h2>Ping</h2>');
    echo('<pre>' . json_encode($p, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT) . '</pre>');
    if ($p->authenticated == true) {
        echo '<p>Authenticated!</p>';
    }

    // Create a simple transaction for $100 using the fluent transaction builder
    $tb = new Avalara\TransactionBuilder($client, "ABC", Avalara\DocumentType::C_SALESINVOICE, 'ABC');
    $t = $tb->withAddress('SingleLocation',$address,null,null, $city,$state,$pincode, $country)
        ->withLine($price, 1, null, "P0000000")
        ->create();

    // echo('<h2>Transaction #1</h2>');
    // echo('<pre>' . json_encode($t, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT) . '</pre>');
    // echo '<pre>';print_r($t);

    $ta=$t->totalTax;

    // die();
    return response($ta)
        ->header('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
```

Comment: Your question is very unclear. What do you want to store, when and where? Please give us some examples of what you want to happen and then what currently happens.

Comment: If I understood well you want to set json response from ajax request in php variable. As much as I know it is not possible or it is if you write js in .php file but is completly useless. Because request is done, you got response and your js script wiil do something with it but that happens in your browser, so php is not relevant any more...